# GWT/GXT tag editor?

Tags: jquery, gwt, tags, editor, gxt

I'm looking for a GWT (or GXT) based tag editor control similar to http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de or http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html or even the StackOverflow tag editor (on the edit page). I couldn't find anything searching for such terms in Google, I was wondering if anyone had ever come across one, perhaps known by a different description or name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check this blog [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete), it has something similar with the components you need here is a demo [here](http://demo.raibledesigns.com/gwt-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make this on your own in gwt. Use the firebug in the tag editor component (which you have mentioned in the question) and see the source code to get better idea.

1) Create some panel with border which looks like text box.For example HorizontalPanel.

2) Add the text box with height and width matches to the horizontal panel.Now user can focus in the text box.

3) Once tag is added create a label for the given input tag then add that label at the first   position of panel. Now label appears in the first position. Then textbox appears. It will look like  stackoverflow tag editor.